# Problems connecting a postgresql db to an app running on tomcat

Tags: java, jpa, netbeans-8, tomcat8, postgresql-9.4

I explain you my problem. 
I try to create a web app using netbeans and tomcat. I've created the backend of the app which provide services for the frontend. The back end is connected to a postgresql db and manages entities thanks to a persistence unit using eclipseLink (JPA 2.1). I use last version of each component.

Now I'd like to use these services in the frontend so I included the .jar of the backend in my project. The probleme is in the connecion between tomcat and the db. After many hours of research i've come to these config files :

web.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="3.1" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd">
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>controleurMaintenance</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>controleur.ActionServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>controleurMaintenance</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/controleurMaintenance</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<session-config>
    <session-timeout>
        30
    </session-timeout>
</session-config>
<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>connection.html</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
<resource-ref>
    <res-ref-name>java:jdbc/maintenanceDB</res-ref-name>
    <res-type>javax.sql.DataSource</res-type>
    <res-auth>Container</res-auth>
    <res-sharing-scope>Shareable</res-sharing-scope>
</resource-ref>
</web-app>
```

context.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Context path="jdbc/Maintenance_webInterface">
<Resource auth="Container" name="java:comp/env/jdbc/maintenanceDB"               type="javax.sql.DataSource" user="paul" password="1234" driverClassName="org.postgresql.Driver"    url="jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/Maintenance_db" maxActive="20" schema="public" maxIdle="2" maxAwaits="-1" validationQuery="select true;"/>
</Context>
```

persistence.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.1" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence"      xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_1.xsd">
  <persistence-unit name="MaintenancePU" transaction-type="JTA">
     <provider>org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider</provider>
    <jta-data-source>java:comp/env/jdbc/MaintenanceDB</jta-data-source>
    <properties>
      <property name="javax.persistence.schema-generation.database.action"     value="create"/>
    </properties>
  </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

In brief I've tried to consider it a data source. I've not touched server.xml. And I got javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: the name jdbc/MaintenanceDB is not linked to this context. Exception varied depending on the change I make. Sometimes it seems to find the db but fails querying it...

Any help would be very appreciated. 
Thank you very much, if you need more information, please just ask.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try following in your context.xml file please

```
<Resource auth="Container" driverClassName="org.postgresql.Driver" maxActive="20" maxIdle="2" maxWait="-1"
              name="/maintenanceDB" password="1234" removeAbandoned="true" removeAbandonedTimeout="20"
              type="javax.sql.DataSource" url="jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/Maintenance_db" username="paul"
              validationQuery="select true;"/>
```

Cheers 
Anant

Along with this here is another way to bind JNDI data source

```
try {
            // Create initial context
            System.setProperty(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY,
                    "org.apache.naming.java.javaURLContextFactory");
            System.setProperty(Context.URL_PKG_PREFIXES,
                    "org.apache.naming");
            InitialContext ic = new InitialContext();

            ic.createSubcontext("java:");
            ic.createSubcontext("java:comp");
            ic.createSubcontext("java:comp/env");

            // Construct DataSource for staging
            // Construct DataSource for wfms
            PGSimpleDataSource ds = new PGSimpleDataSource();
            ds.setUrl("jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/maintenanceDB");//you might get this from context
            ds.setUser("paul");//you might get this from context
            ds.setPassword("1234");//you might get this from context

            ic.bind("java:comp/env/maintenanceDB", wfmsds);

        } catch (NamingException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Might wanna add this function in servlet init();

Thanks
Anant

Comment: That doesn't look correct either, the name in the context.xml should be **jdbc/maintenanceDB** given the persistence.xml lookup path

Comment: <resource-ref>
    <res-ref-name>java:jdbc/maintenanceDB</res-ref-name>
    <res-type>javax.sql.DataSource</res-type>
    <res-auth>Container</res-auth>
    <res-sharing-scope>Shareable</res-sharing-scope>
</resource-ref>

Comment: You should really edit your answer rather than post in a comment.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answers. Sometimes it seems to work sometimes the same exception (the name "MaintenanceDB" is not link to this context ) occured. In some topics I found there are some changes to make in server.xml about the context also but when I tried it didn't work at all.

Comment: Yes it worked just fine two times in a row and after I got this the name isn't linked to the context exception and even after restarting the server ...